# regex: select all characters before and after a specific string

Tags: php, regex

I want to select all text before and after a specific substring, I used the following expression to do that, but it not selecting all the needed text:

```
/^(?:(?!\<\?php echo[\s?](.*?)\;[\s?]\?\>).)*/
```

for example:

```
$re = '/^(?:(?!\<\?php echo[\s?](.*?)\;[\s?]\?\>).)*/';
$str = 'customFields[<?php echo $field["id"]; ?>][type]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

it will select only this part `customFields[`, while the expected result should be `customFields[` and `][type]`

[check this link for debugging](https://regex101.com/r/aWbEmZ/1)

Comment: Why not use [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `^(?:(?!\<\?php echo[\s?](.*?)\;[\s?]\?\>).)*` uses a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) which matches any character except a newline from the start of the string `^` that fulfills the assertion of the negative lookahead.

That will only match `customFields[`

For your example data you could make use of a tempered greedy token [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0dCHCN/1), but instead you could also just make use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex):

```
^[^[]+\[|<\?php echo\s(.*?)\;\s\?\>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\]\[[^]]*\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zkii7U/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/NVWPS)

For example

```
$re = '/^[^[]+\[|<\?php echo\s(.*?)\;\s\?\>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\]\[[^]]*\]/';
$str = 'customFields[<?php echo $field["id"]; ?>][type]';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => customFields[
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ][type]
        )

)
```

To get a more exact match you might also use capturing groups:

```
^((?:(?!<\?php echo[\s?](?:.*?)\;\s\?>).)*)<\?php echo\s(?:.*?)\;[\s?]\?>(.*)$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WNOFcP/1/) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ZfPnG)

Answer (score 0):

What about using `positive lookarounds`:

```
(.*)(?=\<\?php echo)|(?<=\?\>)(.*)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ph0QX8/1)